# What is the most efficient way to position a anchor element that is located on a list item using JSX or Bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have code that looks like this

```
<li className = "list-group-item list-group-item-success" key ={todo.id}>{todo.text}<a className="edit-todo" onClick={() => props.onEdit(todo)}
          className="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" href="#"></a><a className="delete-todo" onClick={() => props.onDelete(todo)}
          className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" href="#"></a>
```

I would like for the anchor elements to be located on the far right side of the list item. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at badges provided by Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/list-group/#with-badges

Example from docs:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    Cras justo odio
    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">14</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    Dapibus ac facilisis in
    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">2</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    Morbi leo risus
    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">1</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

To answer your question specifically, the [flex utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/) (`.d-flex .justify-content-between .align-items-center`) provided by Bootstrap are what pushes the badge to the right side of the list item while keeping the text on the left. You can use any element inside the list item.